# C# Linq convert collection using groupby

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a class that looks like this

```
public class MyClass
{
   public ComplexType A {get;set;}
   public ComplexTypeB B {get;set;}
}

var myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

I then have a target Dto which looks like this

```
public class MyTargetDto
{
    public ComplexType A {get;set;}
    public List<ComplexTypeB> ListOfB {get;set;}
}
```

It's very similar only that myTargetDto supports grouping by ComplexType

Given a flat list of MyClass, how can I (using Linq) convert it to a target list of MyTargetDto?

Comment: This sounds pretty basic. What have you tried?

Comment: tried .GroupBy(g => g.A).ToList()

Comment: try using "Select" after "GroupBy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this.

```
myList.GroupBy(x=>x.A)
      .Select(x=> new MyTargetDto()
       {
           A= x.Key,
           ListOfB = x.Select(s=>s.B).ToList()
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myList.GroupBy(item => item.A)
    .Select(group => new MyTargetDto
    {
        A = group.Key,
        ListOfB = group.Select(item => item.B).ToList()
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `ComplexType` does not have an own implementation of `Equals` than at first you would need to implement an `IEqualityComparer<ComplexType>`:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<ComplexType>
{
    public bool Equals(ComplexType x, ComplexType y)
    {
        // code to check your complex type for equality
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ComplexType obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use this comparer to group your list using `GroupBy`:

```
List<MyClass> flatList = ...
List<MyTargetDto> result = flatList.GroupBy(e => e.A, e => e.B, new Comparer())
                                   .Select(g => new MyTargetDto {
                                         A = g.Key,
                                         ListOfB = g.ToList()});
                                    .ToList();
```

If `ComplexType` already has an own implementation of `Equals` that works appropriatly, than you can ommit that comparer:

```
List<MyTargetDto> result = flatList.GroupBy(e => e.A, e => e.B)
                                   .Select(g => new MyTargetDto {
                                         A = g.Key,
                                         ListOfB = g.ToList()})
                                    .ToList();
```

The first lambda of `GroupBy` selects the element by which the list is grouped. This will then be the `Key` property in the resulting `IGrouping`.
The second lambda selects the elements that should be contained in that group.

The final `Select` creates for each group a `MyTargetDto`, setting it's `A` property to the `ComplexType` and creating the `ListOfB`.

Answer (score 0):

As already posted by others, a solution would be

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.A, x => x.B)
      .Select(g => new MyTargetDto()
      {
          A = g.Key,
          ListOfB = g.ToList()
      });
```

Just wanted you to see an existing shortcut using a [`GroupBy` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534493(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
myList.GroupBy(x => x.A, x => x.B, (key, g) => new MyTargetDto()
{
    A = key,
    ListOfB = g.ToList()
});
```